# Find the dB in android java

Tags: java, android, android-mediarecorder

I'm trying to get the decibels of a sound in android. I use this method, but the "db" is "-Infinity". Can anybody help me?

```
public void startRecording() throws IOException {

    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".3gp");
    //recorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");
    recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();

    double db = (double) 20*Math.log10(recorder.getMaxAmplitude()/700.0);
    sun.setText(""+db);
}
```

Comment: You need to make this occur on a repeating basis some meaningful time *after* you start the recording process, for example with a timer.  And you should realize that the values will be uncalibrated - you will be measuring dB relative to an *unknown* reference - and potentially different on different phones or in different conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The value `-Infinity` means, that the value of `recorder.getMaxAmplitude()` is `0`. What does it mean? It means you have no sound. Why? Well, there are many reasons. Maybe you are testing on emulator and you didn't configure it properly. Or maybe at the last session you didn't call `release()`. You may want to check `logcat` for any messages.

Comment: No, I test the app on a real device. I send a sms, when it is received, the recorder start, then the audio file is saved on sdcard. I use release() when I stop recording. I really don't know why recorder.getMaxAmplitude() is 0.

Comment: @user3006193 Please take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600364/android-mediarecorder-getmaxamplitude-always-returns-0-on-lg-optimus At the first call it will always return 0

Comment: Hmm...I followed those instructions, but recorder.getMaxAmplitude() is still 0. I really don't know how to solve this.

Comment: @user3006193 maybe you should try on the other device or emulator